# Can I implement property in linq and don't call method twice?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this kind of code in C# and I am interesting if there is better solution to calculate `Name` property:

```
dictItem.valueElement.Select(li => new ItemWithNameAndUrl {
    Name = StringParser.getBeforeString("(", li.InnerText) == string.Empty ?
        li.InnerText : StringParser.getBeforeString("(", li.InnerText), //don't like it
    Url = li.Element("a").Attributes["href"].Value
}).ToList());
```

Is any way to not call `StringParser.getBeforeString` method twice for `Name` property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can explicitly open the scope in the select and store result in a variable:

```
var result = dictItem.valueElement.Select(li =>  {
    var name = StringParser.getBeforeString("(", li.InnerText);
    return new ItemWithNameAndUrl {
        Name = name == string.Empty?li.InnerText : name,
        Url = li.Element("a").Attributes["href"].Value
    }        
}).ToList());
```

Or if you want query syntax use the `let` keyword:

```
var result = (from li in dictItem.valueElement
              let name = StringParser.getBeforeString("(", li.InnerText)
              select new ItemWithNameAndUrl {
                  Name = name == string.Empty ? li.InnerText : name,
                  Url = li.Element("a").Attributes["href"].Value
              }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use `IndexOf` to see if `'('` is present:

```
Name = li.InnerText.IndexOf('(') < 0 ? li.InnerText : StringParser.getBeforeString("(", li.InnerText)
```

Another approach is to use regex instead of `StringParser.getBeforeString`:

```
Name = Regex.Replace(li.InnerText, "(.*$", "")
```

Both approaches assume that `StringParser.getBeforeString` method gets the content of the string before the specified delimiter.

Comment: Regex.Replace is interesting solution, but first one is same as my code(It li.InnerText.IndexOf('(') check's string chars if they equal '(' this character and StringParser.getBeforeString("(", li.InnerText) also check's characters while one of them isn't '(' character). I wanted some kind of variable to remember StringParser.getBeforeString("(", li.InnerText) value in linq to use it. Regex. Replace will help in this situation so thank you. But when asking this question I expect something like @Gilad Green answer. So I mark his answer as answer to this question